# Installing an ssl certificate in order to serve a local web application?

Tags: angular, ubuntu, ssl, https, angular-cli

I need to install a local SSL certificate so that the browser trusts it.  This tutorial has instructions for OS X and Windows, but not Ubuntu.

https://medium.com/@rubenvermeulen/running-angular-cli-over-https-with-a-trusted-certificate-4a0d5f92747a

For example these are the instructions for OS X:

Double click on the certificate (server.crt)
Select your desired keychain (login should suffice)
Add the certificate
Open Keychain Access if it isn’t already open
Select the keychain you chose earlier
You should see the certificate localhost
Double click on the certificate
Expand Trust
Select the option Always Trust in When using this certificate
Close the certificate window
The certificate is now installed.

What would the equivalent be for Ubuntu?

Comment: This Ask Ubuntu link will do the trick: https://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you** can search With => 'How To create SSL certificate By Let's Encrypt in Ubuntu Linux' in **Google** 
and **Keep Learning**

This should do the trick though:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate

Comment: I just added my comment answer and accepted your answer.  Welcome to SO!